# Transfer of value in Excel with condition MACRO

Tags: vba, excel

#### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Please help me create a macro/if else statement that will fill column J if its blank.

eg.

1. Column J must be filled with 9 digit phone number from col k or col l if col j is blank.
2. Retain the phone number in col j if available otherwise cut from col k or l then paste   to col J.
3. Transfer the phone number in col l to col k if its blank.

Criteria:

- Col J must be filled with phone number
- Should be unique phone numbers from col JKL.
- Just transfer phone number from col k or col l to col J if its blank or retain if available.

Comment: apologies to all, since i cannot post a pic yet and i dont know how to post it in excel view type.

Comment: What is the priority of the numbers in columns K and L?  Also what is the source of the data?  You might be able to do this all in your query.

Comment: @jbarker2160 1) there is no priority, i just need to transfer phone number from col K to J if col J is blank same goes for col L to K. 2) Source of data: lists of customers that i need to sort. 3) i don't know how to execute my query please help

Comment: The source of the data is not what it is but where it comes from.  Is it a SQL query? another Excel file?  Also, what if there is a value in columns K and L?

Comment: @jbarker2160 yes you are correct, it comes from another excel file, technically i want to create a cleaner that will sort out everyhting. Lets say theres a valid value (phone number 9 digits) in all col k amd c

Comment: I think that your comment got cut off.  Can you please edit?

Comment: @jbarker2160 yes you are correct, it comes from another excel file, technically i want to create a cleaner that will sort out everyhting. Lets say theres a valid value (phone number 9 digits) in col k and l - just retain them if col j meet the criteria..... criteria for col j: 1) should consist only of 9 digit (phone number) otherwise transfer value from k or l.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code:

```
Sub PhoneNumbers()
    Dim w As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Dim r1 As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set w = Sheet1 'Replace Sheet1 with the (name) of your worksheet.
    Set r = w.UsedRange
    r1 = r.Row
    
    For i = r1 To r1 + r.Rows.Count - 1
        If w.Cells(i, 10).Value = "" Then
            If w.Cells(i, 11).Value = "" Then
                w.Cells(i, 10) = w.Cells(i, 12)
            Else
                w.Cells(i, 10) = w.Cells(i, 11)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: works perfectly! i just notice that there are duplicate phone numbers in col K to col J. See screenshot: http://prntscr.com/4prb9i

Comment: Yes. Based on the criteria you gave me that should be fine.
If this solved your problem, please mark my post as the answer.  There should be a checkmark near "Code:"

Comment: yes that works but can you please help me eliminate duplicate from col l and k to col j, since i posted a criteria above that it should be unique? thanks

Comment: So you just want to delete the values from K and L if there is nothing in J?

Comment: If J is blank then transfer values from K, if K is blank then transfer values from L. If J has values then retain same goes for K and L. Column JKL should consist of unique phone numbers

Comment: @pandzkilla,  you didn't ask to do that.  It should be simple enough for you to modify the code I sent.  And there can be no guarantee of uniqueness if the values are not erased after they are copied.